# Which is best to use, ViewHelper or Partial View?

Tags: view, partial, viewhelper

I was creating a viewhelper because there is logic on the rendering of the content.
But then I realize that I am hardcoding the html inside the viewhelper which is achievable
also using the partial view. Many says that views should not have logic in it.
But if i used viewhelper, i need to recompile the project if i need to change the style.

So my question is when to use viewhelper and when to use partial view?

Answer (score 0):

You can have logic in partial view, simply it should has short has possible like really simple statement like `if/else`, it just a best practices to avoid you to code the whole controller work inside the partial views.